# Create view with few columns and multiple rows from a table with many columns and one row

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a table (or more) with one single row and many columns.

### Table1

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   ...   ColN
val1   val2   val3   ...   valn
```

### Table2

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   ...   ColumnM
val11     val22     val23     ...   valM
```

I want to create a view that take some column values in a table and put it in a row, some other colum value from the table (the same or another) and put it in another row of the view, etc

Somethings like this:

### MyView

```
MyColA   MyColB   MyColC
val5     val6     val7
val15    val16    val17
val13    val14    val19
```

It's possible? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select val5 as MyColA, val6 as MyColB, val7 as MyColC from t1
union all
select val15 as MyColA, val16 as MyColB, val17 as MyColC from t2
union all
. . .
```